# NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "588657600000-0400"

Tags: java

`-588657600000-0400` i am getting my response as like this. I am not able to convert this into Date format as this is a invalid long.

```
new Date(Long.parseLong("/Date(-588657600000-0400)/"));
```

Is there anyway, we can actually construct a new Date Object when we get response String in such formats. This Question is related to this one which was asked earlier. [java.lang.Long.parseLong Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891263/java-lang-long-parselong-exception)

The Exception thrown here is **"04-09 01:39:25.793: E/AndroidRuntime(8011): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "588657600000-0400"**

I tried to look at the Calendar class, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html but could not find a method which would get me Date Object without passing Long.

Comment: There's a hyphen there if you haven't noticed.

Comment: `/Date(-588657600000-0400)/` is not a valid long value...

Comment: Guys, i agree that its not a valid long value, but how would i get the Date... that's actually perfect milliseconds...

Comment: What are you trying to do? How would *you* convert that expression to a `Long`?

Comment: where the -0400 come from ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about split the input string in 2 values ?

```
Date foo2 = new Date(Long.parseLong("-588657600000") + Long.parseLong("-0400"));
```

btw, that date is : `Mon May 07 16:59:59 BRT 1951` hehehe

EDIT :

this dont check the input values, and assume allways will have the minus

```
import java.util.Date;

public class MiMiMi {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input = "/Date(-588657600000-0400)/";
        input = input.replace("/Date(", "");
        input = input.replace(")/", "");

        String[] pair = input.split("-");
        System.out.println(pair[1]);
        System.out.println(pair[2]);

        Date foo = new Date(Long.parseLong("-" + pair[1])
                + Long.parseLong("-" + pair[2]));

        System.out.println(foo);
    }

}
```

Comment: It comes from the service... i get the date string as like this "/Date(-588657600000-0400)/"

Comment: I would just remove "/Date(" and ")/" and split using the "-", after that convert each part, and sum